# How does getElementsByName work in Go/WebAssembly?

Tags: go, webassembly

I am using Go and WebAssembly to do DOM manipulation. If I have something like this:

```
jsDoc := js.Global().Get("document")
getradio := jsDoc.Call("getElementsByName", "myradiobuttons")
```

What type is getradio? how do I find the radio button that was checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Call` will return a [Value](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js#Value) type. The [getElementByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) function in javascript should return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So presumably you can do `getradio.Call("item", 0)`, `getradio.Call("item", 1)`, ect. to get your individual options, and then check if the `checked` property is true: `getradio.Call("item", 0).Get("checked")`.